# Probability distribution for a given pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have the following probability density function :
$$f(x;\theta)=\frac{x^3}{2\theta ^2}\exp\left({-\frac{x^2}{2\theta}}\right)$$

Which distribution corresponds to this function?

Comment: Exponential and Gamma.

Answer (score 3):

This is a special case of a generalized Gamma distribution with PDF
$$f(x,a,b,c) = \frac{ac}{\Gamma(b)}(ax)^{bc-1}e^{-(ax)^c}, \quad(a,b,c>0)$$
and CDF
$$
F(x,a,b,c) = \frac{\gamma(b, (ax)^c)}{\Gamma(b)},$$
where $\gamma\;$ is the incomplete Gamma function.
The parameters for your case are
$$a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\theta}}, \quad b=2, \quad c=2.$$

There are other related generalizations of the Gamma distribution
see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution) or [Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GammaDistribution.html).